# How to create a Dynamic Flowing Sankey Diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-analytics

I am fairly new to D3 and wanted some wisdom on adapting a Sankey Diagram to indicate flow behaviour once a user clicks on a specific 'channel'.

Current Sankey Diagrams reflect only a static view, as this Google Analytics example below:

[image: GA Sankey]

I envision the graph to allow a user to "High-light traffic through this node", but instead of only high-lighting, the user would also be able to see the data flowing, from start to end-points (from left to right). As a starting point, I added the flow over one of Mike Bostock's existing Sankey Charts, as a first prototype (source: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5028304).

[image: "Flowing" Sankey Diagram Mockup]

If possible, the prototype should also be extended to show drop-off flow in red (like the GA example above) at the node itself. Thanks!

Comment: You might look into that: https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/e749224c89f82788cb18

Comment: Wow, that is great! I really love this approach! Is there anyway to also create separate churn-channels that flows vertically downwards and mark particles red that drop-off (just like in the Google Analytics example at the very top) ? The idea of this project is to indicate biggest churn from a funnel. I also looked into this library: https://jakezatecky.github.io/d3-funnel/